# What does the 'sudo -s' command do, and how is it used in this example?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, software-installation, sudo

I have the following doubt. In a tutorial related to a software installation that I am following say that I have to execute the following commands (I am doing it into an **ssh** shell, so this list of steps end with the `exit` command):

```
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get install -y build-essential libtool libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev libudev-dev autoconf automake screen
exit
```

My doubts are:

What exactly does the `-s` parameter do after `sudo` command?

Searching on the web I found that:

> **‑s [command]**
>       The ‑s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in the
>   password database. If a command is specified, it is passed to the
>   shell for execution via the shell's ‑c option. If no command is
>   specified, an interactive shell is executed

It seems to me that the `sudo -s` execute a command using the environment variable of the shell.

But this is not clear for me: in this case what is the command executed with the environment variable? (it only executes `sudo -s` and not `sudo -s [command]`).

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is it gives you a root shell. That's what it's being used for here. There's a good [technical comparison between the `su`, `sudo -i`, `sudo -s` and `sudo su` methods on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-bash) but that's really not relevant here. The code could have used any and would have worked.

The help nugget means a few things:

- It's looking for a command in the `$SHELL` environment variable. If you run `echo $SHELL` you'll probably see `/bin/bash`. That means you'll get a root instance of Bash. I'm sure if you were in `zsh` it would mean you get a root instance of `zsh`.
- If `$SHELL` is empty, it falls back to the default shell defined in `/etc/passwd` for that user.
- If you provide a command (eg `sudo -s whoami`), it's actually running: `sudo /bin/bash -c "whoami"`
- If you don't pass a command,  it doesn't pass a `-c` argument over so you just get an interactive shell.

I've used the phrase "root" several times. By *default* `sudo` is all about running things as root but `sudo` (and su) can run things as other users (if you have permission to do so). I'm only stating this for the pedants who will cry out that `sudo -s -u $USER` doesn't give them a root shell as I promised `-s` would above.

---

And in my *humblest* of opinions, it's really silly to become root for just two commands, not to mention that it could leave a user accidentally running further commands as root. If you want or need to run something as root, just premend the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libtool libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev libudev-dev autoconf automake screen
```

I'd be dubious of any tutorial that suggested getting a root shell, except in the cases where you do have bucketloads of commands to run... And even then, there's scripting.

Comment: Perfect explaination. Now it is all more clear. One last doubt. If I preappend sudo to all the previous commands I will obtain the same final result? is it true or am I missing something?

Comment: @Oli you are 100% correct about Zsh, "sudo -s" logs into a "root" shell as "root" not Super User.

Comment: @AndreaNobili Yeah, that's what `sudo` is generally for; running a command as root without having to manually log in as root.

Comment: FYI I posted an answer below yours and my take on `sudo -s` is drastically different because of my limited knowledge and happening across the situation by accident. Still you might want to read my "humble" answer and possibly refresh your 1/2 decade old answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -s` will run a command in the current directory like a regular user would. For example:

```
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ suspendtime
Nov 12 14:06:27 to Nov 12 17:22:21 lasting 11,754 seconds
Nov 12 22:23:37 to Nov 13 04:24:37 lasting 21,660 seconds
(... SNIP ...)
Dec 02 21:58:49 to Dec 03 04:20:52 lasting 22,923 seconds
Dec 03 05:52:43 to Dec 03 16:37:44 lasting 38,701 seconds

Linux uptime 1,859,356 seconds (21 days, 12 hours, 29 minutes, 16 seconds)
45 Suspends 1,173,341 seconds (13 days, 13 hours, 55 minutes, 41 seconds)
Real uptime 686,015 seconds (7 days, 22 hours, 33 minutes, 35 seconds)

rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ sudo suspendtime
sudo: suspendtime: command not found

rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ sudo -H suspendtime
sudo: suspendtime: command not found

rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ sudo -s suspendtime
Nov 12 14:06:27 to Nov 12 17:22:21 lasting 11,754 seconds
(...SNIP...)
Dec 03 05:52:43 to Dec 03 16:37:44 lasting 38,701 seconds

Linux uptime 1,859,431 seconds (21 days, 12 hours, 30 minutes, 31 seconds)
45 Suspends 1,173,341 seconds (13 days, 13 hours, 55 minutes, 41 seconds)
Real uptime 686,090 seconds (7 days, 22 hours, 34 minutes, 50 seconds)
```

Of course using `-s` instead of prefixing the command with `./` may not be that great of a time saving.